# Is there a font that uses glyf table point values to align compound glyph components?

Tags: typography, opentype

For compound glyphs a font has to specify where the components of the glyph are positioned. This is usually done with s and y coordinates, but the `glyf` table allows using point values to align the component. This is indicated by setting the `ARGS_ARE_XY_VALUES` flag to false and will align a point from the current component to a point of the previous components. OpenType 1.9 has improved [documentation on this feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/glyf#composite-glyph-description), so it is quite clear how it should work.

In order to test if font renderers implement this feature correctly, I need a font that actually uses point values for aligning compound glyph components.

Does such a font exist?

**Edit:**

I have run a little script over all fonts in Google Fonts. Here is the result:

`1580` fonts containing `2121337` glyphs in total were examined. `476367` of all glyphs were compound glyphs.

Number of compound glyphs using point values: `0`

So at least none of the 1580 fonts on Google Font uses point values in compound glyphs. Still, there are thousands of fonts out there that are not on Google Fonts, so I am still hoping to find a font that does.

Comment: Definitely something to ask over on https://typedrawers.com instead. Also note that what you're asking about is _only_ applicable to TrueType flavoured OpenType fonts, which rely on the `loca`+`glyf` tables. It does not apply to SVG or CFF/CFF2 OpenType fonts, so that "for compound glyphs" should be "for truetype compound glyphs". That said, this sounds like you should be checking https://github.com/simoncozens/test-fonts and related projects.